# .net, SQLDataTableAdapters 

Tags: asp.net, linq, .net-3.5

I have a sql query method using SQL data table adapters in .xsd file and need to be able to dynamically change the connection string to that method in the code behind.  I can't figure out how to access the methods properties from code behind.

method is IsValidDock(), simply checks database for a particular dock number and returns bool.

basically I am instantiating the query in my code behind by

Dim SQLCommands As New SQLDataTableAdapters.SQLCommands()

I thought I could get to the properties of the method by

SQLCommands.IsValidDock(). some properties.  This is not working, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better question, may be, though, why do you need to change this connection on the fly? Could you just change the definition and call it a day? Do you have multiple database servers that you are working against? The connection strings get stored in the configuration for the project, so if this is a situation where you need a different connection in your test and production environments, then you can just have two config files.

Assuming that is not a solution, read on ...

If I remember correctly, the SqlDataTableAdapter objects spat out by the XSD parser in Visual Studio are sub-classes of SqlDataAdapter, are they not (you can find out in Visual Studio by right clicking on a reference to one and choosing "Go to definition")? If so, you can just new up an instance of the generated class (there should be a generated .cs or .vb file for it in your project) and pass it a customized SqlConnection object.

There is no interface for changing the connection of a data adapter after it has been created. The adapter opens the connection when you do anything that needs it (call Fill(), Insert(), etc.) and only closed when the SqlDataAdapter is disposed.

Comment: This is a custom barcode scanner program for a companies warehouse.  They have several warehouses around the country and want to be able to change database connections on the fly depending on which warehouse they are in at the time.  THey want to be able to make a selection on the handheld app that identifies the warehouse and that changes the connection string to that particular database.  I can achieve this by using a custom sql connection class but the client really likes using sqldatatableadapters.  Of course the original designer of the app couldn't make it work so they turned to us.

Answer (score 0):

TableAdapters are generated as partial classes, so you could extend that TableAdapter and add the correct initialization for the connection property of the adapter in there.

Hope this helps
Jaime